# How do I sort in excel and keep the rows together in sets of three?

Tags: microsoft-excel

You can see below my list. I want to be able to sort by column 4, which is yes or no. When I sort the “yes” I won’t A1-A3. A4-A6 needs to stay together with the “no”
And on and on. Is there a way to do this?

```
A1 123 Main         yes  
A2
A3                               
                                                 
A4 456 Main         no  
A5
A6                               
                                                 
                                                 
789 Any              yes                                     
                                                 
                                                 
1010 Other          no
```

Comment: you'll need a helper column that somehow gets the yes/no from the relevant cells and then concatenates that with the row number. Otherwise you'll need to write a program with VBA/office script

Comment: Thank you for the help. I can look it up but any advice where to start on a helper column?

Comment: Sometimes there is no meaningful way to filter/sort/calculate your existing spreadsheet because the structure doesn't exist. So the creating a helper column is normally done to aide in performing that task. For example I may put in a helper column called index and number 1 to how ever many rows of data I have then I can sort by another column, and to return back to my original state I resort by the index.

Answer (score 1):

In a helper column use a formula:

```
=IF(LOOKUP("z",D$2:D2)="yes",0,1000)+ROW()
```

and then sort by this helper column.
[image: Sort grouped rows]